Video Playback is not working in my gstreamer python3 command
I'm currently trying to stream,and save to file with the code below using gstreamer in python3 , the gstreamer piplines work fine in the terminal but when i use them in the python code i can succefully stream save and not playble file. i think the not playble video issue is coming from not ending the gstreamer piplines in python3 properly because when i execute the pipline in terminal i use -e to stop it but i can't use that in python . i would appreciate it any advice thank you.
the gstreamer pipeline(streames and saves playble files):
"""
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src io-mode=4 device=/dev/video0 do-timestamp=true ! 'video/x-raw, format=UYVY, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1' ! queue ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h264enc bitrate=16000000 ! h264parse ! tee name=t ! queue ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://ww.google.com' t. ! queue ! qtmux ! filesink location=/home/nvidia/Desktop/RGB_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S').mp4 -e 

"""
the python3 code (streams and doesn't save files proprely) :
"""
import gi
from time import sleep

gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
gi.require_version("GstApp", "1.0")

from gi.repository import Gst, GstApp, GLib

Gst.init()
_ = GstApp



pipeRGB ="v4l2src io-mode=4 device=/dev/video0 do-timestamp=true ! video/x-raw, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1 ! queue ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h264enc bitrate=16000000 ! h264parse ! tee name=t ! queue ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://ww.google.com' t. ! queue ! qtmux ! filesink location=/home/nvidia/Desktop/RGB_video.mp4"




pipeIR = "v4l2src io-mode=4 device=/dev/video1 do-timestamp=true ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=512, framerate=30/1 ! queue ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h264enc bitrate=5000000 ! h264parse ! tee name=t ! queue ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://rtmp://ww.google.com' t. ! queue ! qtmux ! filesink location=/home/nvidia/Desktop/IR_video.mp4"


pipelineRGB = Gst.parse_launch(pipeRGB)
pipelineRGB.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
pipelineIR = Gst.parse_launch(pipeIR)
pipelineIR.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)



try:
    while True:
        sleep(0.1)
        print("Streaming...")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("""\r\n
    ============================
    Keyboard Interrrupt received
    ============================""")
    pass

print("StoppingIR...")
pipelineIR.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
sleep(2)
print("StoppingRGB...")
pipelineRGB.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
print("Stopped.")

"""
